# Como diferenciar tipos estáticos de tipos dinâmicos?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

tudo bem com vocês?

Tive hoje mais uma aula de POO, e o assunto de hoje foi principio da substituição e os tipos estáticos e dinâmicos.

Não entendi bem a definição destes conceitos e qual a sua utilidade... Será que alguém me poderia explicar isto com algum exemplo simples de se entender?

Agradeço desde já a vossa ajuda.

Comment: Mais pode ser visto em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=tipagem%20din%c3%a2mica%20e%20est%c3%a1tica

Answer (score 1):

Muito bem, vamos lá.

Tipo estáticos são definidos no momento em que se escreve o código e verificados em tempo de compilação, e não permitem que sejam atribuídos valores que não se enquadrem no tipo definido. Por exemplo, uma variável de tipo **int** só pode receber valores int (ou short, considerando-se Java) ou valores inteiros de outros tipos sendo necessário a utilização de casting. Tipo estáticos são comuns em linguagens compiladas.

Tipos dinâmicos aceitam qualquer valor para sua atribuição. Utilizando o exemplo de uma linguagem dinamicamente tipada (javascript), pode-se definir uma variável e atribuir um valor numérico a ela, e algumas linhas depois alterar o valor para um tipo string. Tipos dinâmicos são comuns em linguagens interpretadas (Javascript, Python, etc).

Mais um exemplo: a expressão int a = "1" resulta em erro de compilação em uma linguagem estaticamente tipada (C++, Java, etc).

Mas as expressões var a = "1"; a = 5; a = { name: "asdf"}; 
são interpretadas e executadas normalmente em uma linguagem dinamicamente tipada (Javascript).

Comment: Esses conceitos se aplicam a hierarquia de classes? Se sim, como?